# Sagemaker estimators metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I created a custom Tensorflow 2 model and, to train it on a Sagemaker pipeline, I created an estimator with a metrics definition for the validation binary accuracy of the trained model:

```
estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point=code_entry,
                   source_dir=code_dir,
                   role=sagemaker_role,
                   instance_type='local',
                   instance_count=1,
                   model_dir='s3://some-bucket/model/',
                   hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
                   output_path='s3://some-bucket/results/',
                   framework_version='2.8',
                   py_version='py39',
                   metric_definitions=[
                        {
                            "Name": "binary_accuracy",
                            "Regex": "val_binary_accuracy=(\d+\.\d+)?",
                        }
                    ],
                   script_mode=True)
```

According to [Sagemaker's Estimator documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html), by setting the metrics definition, Sagemaker will extract metrics from the training logs using a regex:

> metric_definitions (list[dict[str, str] or list[dict[str, PipelineVariable]]) – A list of dictionaries that defines the metric(s) used to evaluate the training jobs. Each dictionary contains two keys: ‘Name’ for the name of the metric, and ‘Regex’ for the regular expression used to extract the metric from the logs.

The trained model metrics are then available in the properties of the training job in the `FinalMetricDataList`object.

In the training logs I can see the log below, which matches the regex in the estimator's metrics definition:

```
2wn9x0rkaf-algo-1-43gci | INFO:root:val_binary_accuracy=0.5
```

But when I try to access the metric with the code below:

```
step_training.properties.FinalMetricDataList['binary_accuracy'].Value
```

... I get the following error in my conditional step that checks if the metric is higher than a threshold:

```
 Pipeline step 'CheckAccuracyEvaluation' FAILED. Failure message is: {'Get': "Steps.TrainingStep.FinalMetricDataList['binary_accuracy'].Value"} is undefined.
```

What am I doing wrong here? How to get the metrics from a trained model using a Sagemaker estimator using script mode?

Comment: Can you try the below regex and check "'val_binary_accuracy'=([0-9]+(.|e\-)[0-9]+),?"

Comment: Hi @ArunLokanatha, I tried and unfortunately the result is the same: "Pipeline step 'CheckAccuracyEvaluation' FAILED. Failure message is: {'Get': "Steps.TrainingStep.FinalMetricDataList['validation:error'].Value"} is undefined."